# Determining if a parametric curve intersects a plane at a right angle

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametric

Given a plane described by
$$
x + 8y + 12z = 162
$$
and a curve described by
$$
\begin{align}
x &= t\\
y &= t^2\\
z &= t^3
\end{align}
$$
I want to find out if the curve intersects the plane at a right angle.

I started by substituting $x$, $y$, and $z$ into the equation for the curve and solving for $t$ which would find the time at which the intersection occurs. After this, I'm not entirely sure how I would go about solving it. I need a vector that describes the direction that the curve would be pointing at that time, so that I could then take the cross product with the normal vector of the plane, $\langle1,8,12\rangle$. Another issue with this method is that it requires the solution to a cubic equation which is not trivial on paper. Is there a better method to go about solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have found the time $t_0$ of intersection the derivative with respect to time at $t_0$ will well you the direction is is moving. Since
$$r(t)=\begin{pmatrix}t\\t^2\\t^3\end{pmatrix}\text{ we have }r'(t)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2t\\3t^2\end{pmatrix}$$
and now it's a matter of plugging in the intersection point.

---

But since you only want to check if it's orthogonal you could work in reverse and find the times $t$ at which the directional vector is perpendicular to the plane (this will give you a quadratic equation) and check if these are intersection points.

Answer (score 2):

The normal vector to the plane is [1,8,12]. The tangent vector to the curve is $[1,2t,3t^2]$.Note that neither of these vectors is the $\mathbf 0$ vector. So the curve intersects the plane at right angles iff these vectors are scalar multiples of each other iff they are linearly dependent iff their cross-product is $\mathbf 0$ at the particular value of $t$ where they intersect.